# Hibernate - Encountered failure rolling back failed commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, firebird

I have an application with following technologies:

- Spring 4.2.2
- Hibernate 5.1.0
- Maven
- Apache Tomcat 8.0
- Firebird 2.2

When I'm running my project it works fine at first. But after some time I am receiving an error during login procedure.

In login procedure I am updating user using UserService. And here I am getting error: **Encountered failure rolling back failed commit**. I spend some time on this and I can't figured out why I am receiving that error.

Error Message:

```
DEBUG JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl:240 - Encountered failure rolling back failed commit
org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@248f59f3 is closed
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at pl.aemon.smom.dao.access.EklientDao.commitTransaction(EklientDao.java:170)
    at pl.aemon.smom.dao.access.UserService.update(UserService.java:36)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.AuthenticationCaptchaFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCaptchaFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.LoginPostFilter.doFilter(LoginPostFilter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is UserService class with update method which cause an error (in line 36):

```
public class UserService
{
    private EklientDao userDao;

    public UserService()
    {
        if(userDao == null)
            userDao = new EklientDao();
    }

    public UserService(HibernateUtil util)
    {
        if(userDao == null)
            userDao = new EklientDao(util);
    }
    public void update(Eklient entity)
    {

        userDao.startTransaction();
        userDao.update(entity);
        userDao.commitTransaction(); //36 line
    }
}
```

UserDao class with commitTransaction() method which cause en error:

```
public class EklientDao implements SmomDaoInterface<Eklient, String> 
{
    private Session currentSession;
    private HibernateUtil util;

    private Transaction currentTransaction; //from org.hibernate

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EklientDao.class);

    public EklientDao() {
        openCurrentSession();
    }

    public EklientDao(HibernateUtil util)
    {
        this.util = util;
        openCurrentSession();
    }

    public void commitTransaction()
    {
        if(currentTransaction != null)
        {
            if(currentTransaction.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)
                currentTransaction.commit(); //170 line
        }
    }


}
```

Hibernate config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:firebirdsql://XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

--Edit--

I am using UserService to update user during login authentication in AuthenticationProviderImpl class. This is example:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    HibernateUtil hibernateUtil;

     @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

     String name = authentication.getName().toUpperCase();
     String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

     if(userService==null)
            userService = new UserService(hibernateUtil);

    Session session = hibernateUtil.restartSession();

    userService.userDao().setCurrentSession(session);
     Eklient user = userService.findById(name);

     user.setSomeDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
     userService.update(user); //HERE IS AN ERROR


     //....///

     return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);

}
```

And this is my HibernateUtil class for building, restarting, opening sessions:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static Session currentSession;

    private Session currentScopedSession;

    private static List<SessionFactory> sessionFactories = new ArrayList<SessionFactory>();
   public HibernateUtil(){}

   public static final void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        HibernateUtil.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    public static final Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }


    public Session restartSession()
    {
        if(sessionFactory == null || sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
            sessionFactories.add(sessionFactory);
        }
        if(currentScopedSession != null && currentScopedSession.isOpen()) {
            currentScopedSession.close();
            System.out.println("Session opened");
            currentScopedSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return currentScopedSession;
    }

    public final Session getCurrentScopedSession() {
        if(sessionFactory == null || sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
            sessionFactories.add(sessionFactory);
        }
        if(currentScopedSession == null) {
            System.out.println("Session opened");
            currentScopedSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return currentScopedSession;
    }

    public final void setCurrentScopedSession(Session currentScopedSession) {
        this.currentScopedSession = currentScopedSession;
    }

}
```

---EDIT 2---

I have noticed earlier exception before this:

```
2020-04-25 20:55:16 ERROR SessionImpl:3166 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Session is closed!]
2020-04-25 20:55:16 DEBUG JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl:265 - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at pl.aemon.smom.dao.access.AdminLogDao.commitTransaction(AdminLogDao.java:136)
    at pl.aemon.smom.dao.access.AdminLogService.persist(AdminLogService.java:29)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.AuthenticationCaptchaFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCaptchaFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at pl.aemon.smom.config.LoginPostFilter.doFilter(LoginPostFilter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The fact your transaction and session are member fields of a DAO seems fishy to me. What is the scope of those beans? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an earlier exception (or a longer cause-chain for the exception)?

Comment: actually it is an earlier exception, didn't even notice, i will post it to my question

Comment: The fact that `HibernateUtil` has `private static Session currentSession;` and `private Session currentScopedSession;` seems like a possible cause to me: under concurrent access you might mix up sessions and share an already closed session.

Comment: do you have any tips how should i fix this?

Comment: Make sure you don't use static, and I guess `HibernateUtil` should be session-scoped, or find a different solution to that. And consider leveraging more of the power of the Hibernate support in Spring Framework (and other Spring libraries), instead of trying to roll your own.